# Open WIth dialog in Java

Tags: java

I was wondering if there's a cross platform way to mimic the Windows Open With dialog from inside a Java Swing application.  My application is an editor for elearning packages and one of the users wanted to be able to open the content files in the editor of their choice from within the application, resources are generally HTML files, images, css, javascript, but can be any type of content that can run in a browser.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you may be able to do something with JDIC (Java Desktop Integration Components).

https://jdic.dev.java.net/documentation/Examples.html

Take a look at the package `org.jdesktop.jdic.filetypes`

https://jdic.dev.java.net/nonav/documentation/javadoc/jdic/org/jdesktop/jdic/filetypes/package-summary.html

> Provides classes for associating
>   applications with file types and
>   accessing a registered file type
>   association.
>
> Every desktop allows the user to view
>   files with the associated
>   applications. Usually a desktop comes
>   with a registry that allows the user
>   to associate applications with file
>   types. An association includes
>   information like a MIME type, file
>   extensions, and actions that could be
>   applied to the file type. By accessing
>   the association information, the
>   desktop could invoke the appropriate
>   applications to handle a file, display
>   an URL or send an email.