# Eclipse: How to prompt user to choose an application to open a file with?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to open arbitrary files from Eclipse. Currently I'm doing it like that:

```
if (((File) selectedElement).isFile()) {
    try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open((File) selectedElement);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO prompt for the appropriate application to open this file.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this only works, if the OS has a default application associated with the file type. That's why, if there isn't any default application defined, I want to ask the user which application I should use. But I have no idea how to 1) find a list of available application and 2) open the file with that application. Any hints how to implement that in a platform-independent way?

Comment: Do you mean "from Eclipse", as in, this is an RCP app or plugin; or do you just mean Eclipse is your IDE? Because using Desktop.open() isn't the Eclipse way to do this in the first place.

Comment: I'm writing a plugin. This plugin has the possibility to browse through all files of the OS. Now if the files aren't text files or java files, I want to open the files with the default application in the OS. For example docx documents with MS Word. This works as long as the file type is associated with a application in the OS. If the filetype has not yet a default application in the OS, my approach fails and I want to ask the user which application I should use. But I don't know how I can do that.

Answer (score 4):

Any solution I can think of would depend on the OS.  For example if your application is running in windows you could provide the user with a list of all *.exe files in the *Program Files* folder. Or all applications in the /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/share/bin for a linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

There's already another thread marked as resolved for this, check that out: [Open WIth dialog in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238991/open-with-dialog-in-java)