# Get filepath of opening file with executable java-application by GUI-OS

Tags: java, executable

I want to make a java application to be runable. Let's say I generate an .exe file to use with windows. Now I'm able to link it to a specific file-type, as example: txt-files. If I open a txt-file it should be opened with my application. You all know this thing from pdf-files, jpg-files and so on.

But where goes the filepath of this txt-file in java? I have to know / work with it to do the right things with the file.

Comes the full path at args[0] to my main method or is this only for openings by terminal?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open WIth dialog in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238991/open-with-dialog-in-java)

Comment: nope, if I see it right, the other post is to make the "open with" dialog of windows accessable out of a java application. What I'm searching is how to get the file which is using the "open with" dialog to open my application.